How can an old implementation be removed from the gradle for good?
I added the androidx-material3-window-size-class-android implementation in my build.gradle.kts (app) file, and got a
"- Problem: In version catalog libs, alias 'androidx-material3-window-size-class-android' is not a valid alias."
which prevented rebuilding gradle.
After removing that implementation from  build.gradle.kts I still keep getting the same error, even after invalidating Caches and downloading everything again. Should I just create a new project and copy the code from the broken one?
In existing projects downloaded from GitHub for codelabs (eg:Reply) the implementation ("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class") works just fine, but if I create a new project and add it to the build it just goes balooney

Try deleting the .gradle folder in your user's home directory.

.gradle folder deleted, no luck, error is still there unfortunately.

implementation(libs.androidx.material3.windowsizeclass) 
[libraries]
androidx-material3-windowsizeclass = { module = "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class", version.ref = "material3WindowSizeClass" } 
[versions]
material3WindowSizeClass = "1.2.1"

That solved the problem for me. I hope it's helpful.

Thanks a lot for the Answer, apparently the basic solution to my question was to just delete the library from the libs.versions.toml file as well (version catalog), a file I never even noticed before! Sorry I can't upvote you with my plebeian status but you really solved my problem!
